# How can I connect my app from android studio with amadeus api

Tags: java, android, amadeus

I spent a lot of time and energy trying to connect my android studio app with amadeus api but I have no success. I looked at the amadeus for developers site, also at the github amadeus sdk but that didn't helped me. I would like to know is it possible to connect android studio app with amadeus api, and if it is, how to do that. I really do not have any idea what I have to do. If that's not possible, what should I use to have search flights and search hotels options in my app? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Java SDK](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java) to integrate the Amadeus APIs in your Android application. Note that for Android you will need to make asynchronous calls to use the APIs.